# Не виден viewPager при match_constraints

Tags: android, recyclerview, coordinator-layout

[image]

Нужно создать такой экран. Картинка должна скрываться, `Toolbar` оставаться. Но тут проблема с высотой `ViewPager`. Eсли для `ViewPager` установить match_constraints то фрагмент `ViewPager` вообще не отображается. То же и с `match_parent`. Только если поставить конкретное значение, например `250dp`, тогда становится видимым. Чем может быть вызвано такое поведение и как можно решить проблему, чтоб была нормальная прокрутка? Может у кого то есть примеры работы `CollapsingToolbarLayout` и `TabLayout` с `RecyclerView`

Структура такая:

```
   <CoordinatorLayout>
        <AppBarLayout>
            <CollapsingToolbarLayout
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
                <ConstraintLayout 
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
                       <ImageView/>
                       <ImageView/>
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
                <Toolbar
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
                    <LinearLayout>
                        <ImageView/>
                        <TextView/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </Toolbar>
            </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </AppBarLayout>

        <NestedScrollView>
                <ConstraintLayout>
                    <TabLayout/>
                    <ViewPager/>
                </ConstraintLayout>
        </NestedScrollView>
    </CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Для чего вы оборачиваете  `TabLayout` и `ViewPager` в `ConstraintLayout` и `NestedScrollView`? Поставьте просто `TabLayout` и `ViewPager`, и если контент во `ViewPager` должен прокручиваться, реализуйте это в разметке, которую используют фрагменты находящиеся во `ViewPager`. И еще, в реализации `ViewPager` для синхронной прокрутки с другими `View`-элементами вы должны добавить к `ViewPager`: `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Comment: Я оборачиваю в `ConstraintLayout` потому что там еще `RatingBar` и кнопка. Добавлял без них вместе с `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` все равно прокрутка почему то работает отдельно на `AppBarLayout` и `ViewPager`

Comment: Правильно, сначала AppBar скроллится, а потом содержимое ViewPager